# How can I control a DC circuit via a high voltage AC signal?

Tags: transistors, signal-processing, thyristor

I have a low voltage circuit of 9V DC supply voltage and a bunch of LEDs, and another circuit with 50V AC voltage. I want the DC circuit to work only if there is current flowing in the AC circuit. I searched on the net and I didn't find an adequate solution. I find that a transistor can get a smaller DC current in the base to control a greater current in the collector, but what if the current in the base is greater in the base?

Comment: A relay would work and provide isolation between the two circuits. How much current are you switching and how precise do you need the switching to be?

Comment: A really crude solution would be to power the 9V DC circuit from the 50V AC supply, using a diode (that's rated for your usecase with a good enough margin, for peace of mind) to rectify and a capacitor to smooth it to a 50V DC, then regulating it to a 9V supply using something like a 7809 or similar.

Comment: Having said that, if you already have the power source for the 9V circuit and just want it to be switched depending on the AC circuit (or if you can't source enough current from your 50V AC supply to power the 9V DC circuit), then a relay or some sort of opto-isolator should do the trick. You might be able to use a single transistor if they share a ground, too.

Comment: Switch when AC current is flowing or AC is presented?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický when it's flowing.

Comment: @QuickishFM what type of relay should I use

Comment: A current monitoring relay or current control relay.

Comment: What is the current drawn in the 50 V AC circuit?